# When do I do a preload for HTML5 audio?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, audio

I am developing a mobile web app with HTML5 audio. Much has been said here and on other forums about the fact that you cannot do an auto-play on mobile devices and I worked around that by forcing the user to touch the screen just once to start the app, firing a dummy audio load on that touch, then loading and playing audio files automatically using the src parameter. This works very well and is supported even by IOS7.

An example with short audio files is at [test audio](http://www.gfx.com/test). View source to see the rather simple code.

In the actual app, I want to follow this logic but I need to ensure that each audio file is completely loaded before playing it. My question is, is the preload directive issued once when the main audio object is created and thus, applies to all files that are subsequently loaded, or do I have to issue it once for every file loaded. And if the latter, is it before or after the src directive?

```
    myaudio = new Audio();
    myaudio.preload='auto';
    myaudio.play();
    myaudio.pause();
```

or

```
    myaudio.preload='auto';
    myaudio.src = "/js/crow.mp3";
    myaudio.play();
```

or

```
    myaudio.src = "/js/crow.mp3";
    myaudio.preload='auto';
    myaudio.play();
```

Thanks for any insight you may lend.

Comment: I have limited experience dealing directly with html 5 media tags...so when in doubt I search the Mozilla MDN docs...here's a **[page with media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Media_events)** that will likely help   Although they refer to `<audio>` tag on the page... I believe from quick serfing will be same for `new Audio` object

Comment: So just to clarify - you want to make sure that you start playing the audio **only** when the entire file has been loaded?

Comment: Yes. And audio tags are not an issue here. I am doing it entirely with javascript. These pages are dynamically delivered. I don't want streaming audio if I can help it. I already preload all of my images for a particular page, I just want to ensure that the audio file is preloaded as well. I know I can write a loop, but the preload parameter is much simpler if it will work.